# Laravel retrieving column value from query gives error

Tags: mysql, laravel, controller

I am currently working on a school project and am trying to retrieve values from a successfully ran query. The query is as so:

```
$airportQuery = Airport::where('id', '=', $airport)->get(); //Returns all columns of users selected airportId
```

I am trying to retrieve a column "extendedcenterlineLong" and "extendedcenterlineLat". I am doing this by running

```
array[] = $airportQuery->extendedcenterLong;
array[] = $airportQuery->extendedcenterLat;
```

(The array isn't named array[] either) When I try to run myQuery I get this error 
[image]

I have not been able to fix this issue, what am I doing wrong?
Many Thanks!

EDIT: I also have these queries to get the previous row or next row from waht the user selects

```
$previous = Airport::where('id', '<', $airport)->max('id'); //Returns the previous rows values from users current selected airportId
$next = Airport::where('id', '>', $airport)->min('id'); //Returns the next rows values from users current selected airportId
```

EDIT: I solved the problem by doing `$airportQuery->first()->column_name`. For some reason when I printed out $airportQuery there were two items that were arrays of the column info that were identical to each other, a copy basically.

Comment: try to print out the `$airportQuery->extendedcenterLong` to ensure that you get the value or not

Comment: I tried doing print_r($airportQuery->extendedcenterLong); but i get no print at the top. I tried printing just $airportQuery but I an array of the correct information and then another copy gets printed with the same information, is that an issue?

Comment: maybe the issue is `$airport`.. it does not recognize the variable.. lets try to print it out and make sure that the variable has value / recognized

Comment: I fixed the problem by calling $airportQuery->first()->extendedcenterLong Thank you for all your help

Answer (score 2):

You can just do a

```
$airportQuery = Airport::where('id', '=', $airport)->first();
```

i guess above should work.